# mapper_parsing_exception failed to parse Error in elasicsearch using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am new to `elasticsearch`. I am implementing `elasticsearch` in `node.js(express)`. I have these 2 functions inside my `elasticsearch.js`

```
/** Mapping data to be stored in elastic search**/
function initMapping() {
    return elasticClient.indices.putMapping({
        index : indexName,
        type : "document",
        includeTypeName: true,
        body : {
            properties : {
                title : {type : 'text'},
                content : {type : 'text'},
                suggest : {
                    type : 'completion',
                    analyzer : 'simple',
                    search_analyzer : 'simple'
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

/** Function to add coument to index**/
function addDocumentToIndex(doc) {
    return elasticClient.index({
        index : indexName,
        type : 'document',
        body : {
            title : doc.title,
            content : doc.content,
            suggest : {
                input : doc.title.split(' '),
                output : doc.title
            }    
        }
    })
}
```

And in my `app.js` file i have following code related to `elasticsearch`

```
elastic.isIndexExist().then(function(exists){
  console.log('-- Exist Response-- :', exists)
  if(exists){
    return elastic.deleteIndex()
  }
}).then(function() {
  console.log('-- In InitIndex Func--')
  elastic.initIndex()
  .then(function(initResponse){ 
    console.log('--init response-- ', initResponse)
    if (initResponse.acknowledged) {
      return elastic.initMapping()
    }
  })
  .catch(function(initIndexError){
    console.log('--Init Index Error-- ', initIndexError)
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log('-- in promies func --')
    var promises = [
      'Thing Explainer',
      'The Internet Is a Playground',
      'The Pragmatic Programmer',
      'The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy',
      'Trial of the Clone',
      'All Quiet on the Western Front',
      'The Animal Farm',
      'The Circle'
    ].map(function(bookTitle){
      console.log('--Book Title-- ', bookTitle)
      return elastic.addDocumentToIndex({
        title : bookTitle,
        content : bookTitle + " content"
      })
    })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log('------Elastic Search Error ----- : ',error)
  })
})
```

And when i runs the app so i get the execution like this

[image]

I have simple `elasticsearch` mapping function named `initMapping` which is doing mapping that how documents will be stored in elasticsearch. And then in `addDocument` function i have document insertion code but i am getting error when it try to add document in `elasticsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully debugging and error reading i got that in latest version of `elasticsearch` suggest's `output` property depreciates now it doesn't exist in latest version. So i changed my `addDocumentToIndex` function to

```
function addDocumentToIndex(doc) {
    console.log('input doc ', doc)
    return elasticClient.index({
        index : indexName,
        type : 'document',
        body : {
            title : doc.title,
            content : doc.content,
            suggest : {
                input : doc.title.split(' ')
            }   
        }
    })
}
```